# How to fix JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)

Tags: python, json, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to follow along with this interactive notebook developed by Google to train an ML model from satellite images: https://colab.research.google.com/github/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/people-and-planet-ai/geospatial-classification/README.ipynb#scrollTo=77c0f36a

All of this code was written by someone else - I'm just trying to follow along and keep ending up with quite a few errors. I've managed to work around some (I essentially have no coding knowledge at all), but some are beyond my skill level. I'm running all of this in a Google Colab notebook.

I keep running into problems with this specific cell of code:

```
import requests

requests.post(
    url=f'{service_url}/ping',
    headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {identity_token}'},
    json={'x': 42, 'message': 'Hello world!'},
).json()
```

The error output is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-3a865e581f23> in <module>()
      4     url=f'{service_url}/ping',
      5     headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {identity_token}'},
----> 6     json={'x': 42, 'message': 'Hello world!'},
      7 ).json()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    896                     # used.
    897                     pass
--> 898         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    899 
    900     @property

/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

Could someone explain to me (like you would to a 5-year-old) what's going wrong with the JSON parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Your `service_url` might be sending some other response (not Json). To view this use `resp.text` and then try to convert it to json using `try and except` method

```py
resp=requests.post(<your_headers_and_url>)

#Print output in text format
print(resp.text)
```

#### Sample Code for Testing

```py
import requests

service_url="https://httpbin.org/"
identity_token="AABBCCDD"
resp=requests.post(
    url=f'{service_url}/post',
    headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {identity_token}'},
    json={'x': 42, 'message': 'Hello world!'},
)

#Print the response in text format
#print(resp.text)

#Then try to convert it to json 
#using try and except method to catch the error
try:
    print(resp.json())
except:
    print("Not Json")
```

Try online compiler to test the code https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/